# Natbib -- change author conjunction in citation call-out from 'and' to '&'

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using natbib, german babel and natbib creates output of the form

```
Foo and Bar (1337)
```

I would like to get

```
Foo & Bar (1337) for citet and
(Foo & Bar 1337) respectively for citep.
```

Comment: What `\bibliographystyle` do you use?

Comment: Hey, im using chicago atm. Anyhow, since I additionally need to have small caps (stupid prof!), I'm looking for that, additionally, anyways... looks like siam and acm dont work with natbib, you got any advice? Thanks

Comment: Can someone please correct the spelling for the word "separation" on the title?

Comment: @Vivi: Spelling corrected.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're using `\bibliographstyle{plainnat}`, put a copy of `plainnat.bst` in your working folder and rename it to `myplainnat.bst` (later, this file should go to the appropriate location in your local TEXMF folder). In this copy, look for `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}` and specifically for `" and "`. Replace the latter with `" \& "` and save your modified copy. Compile your `.tex` file with `\bibliographstyle{myplainnat}`. The expression "and" in citations (but not in the bibliography) should now be replaced with "&".

If you want "&" also as separator in the bibliography, replace every instance of `" and "` in `plainnat` (there should be three of them) with `" \& "`.

EDIT: At least with regard to citations, it works the same way with `chicago.bst`. I don't know how to get small caps with `natbib`, though. My advice would be to switch to [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) -- see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) question for details.

Comment: look also for bbl.and as indicator, which might be used in multi languages styles

Answer (score 2):

One option I have used previously is `\renewcommand{\betweenauthors}{&}` -- however it appears not to work with standard .bst files such as `apalike.bst`.

An alternative is to use the `custom-bib` package to generate your own `.bst` file - it does have an explicit option (AMPERSAND) that lets you choose between an `and` and an `&` in your list of authors.

Using `custom-bib` is as easy as running `latex makebst.tex` (e.g.  `latex /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/custom-bib/makebst.tex` for my installation) and following the prompts.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `plainnat.bst` or `chicago.bst`.

Comment: @lockstep Oupps, doesn't work with `apalike.bst` either; seems I used it in conjunction with a `.bst` file generated using custom-bib; have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I second the use of `custom-bib`.