# Change the appearance of citation call-outs

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, citing, natbib

I write a paper in Chinese and I use `\cite{eaton2002technology}` to reference a paper. I want to change the "and" in "Eaton and Kortum (2002)" into "和".

I also cite a Chinese paper and want to change the "and" in the references list to "、".

The desired result is: "Eaton 和 Kortum (2002)"

mini example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

我的中文文章参考了 \cite{eaton2002technology}

我的中文文章参考了 \cite{fanziyin2010}

\medskip
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{citation}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography file (`citation.bib`)

```
@article{eaton2002technology,
Author = {Eaton, Jonathan and Kortum, Samuel},
Journal = {Econometrica},
Number = {5},
Pages = {1741--1779},
Publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
Title = {Technology, geography, and trade},
Volume = {70},
Year = {2002}}


@article{fanziyin2010,
Author = {范子英 and 张军},
Date-Added = {2016-11-05 15:26:38 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-11-06 06:10:56 +0000},
Journal = {经济研究},
Number = {3},
Pages = {53--64},
Title = {财政分权, 转移支付与国内市场整合},
Volume = {45},
Year = {2010}}
```

IDE:Texpad 1.731

Engine: Xelatex, BibTex

Compiled output of the mini example:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: No one will be able to tell you how to do this until you post [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). We need to know what package (if any) has defined `\cite` and what (I'm even guessing here) `.bst` file is responsible for the citations and references.

Comment: Do you want to submit to a journal? If not, `biblatex`  can handle your issue much better.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Is the solution provided in my answer no good? :-) It's certainly not all that difficult...

Comment: @Mico Yeah, sure it is good. And you said to rename the file. That is good.

Comment: @Johannes_B - I just found [this 5-year-old answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19837/5001), which also deals with `natbib` and `plainnat`. I suppose my new answer isn't all that different from the earlier one, apart from the form of the conjunction (`&` vs. `和`)...

Comment: @Mico TeX and LaTeX are around for many years. This community is also around for a while. The amount of *new* questions will get smaller. Samequestions will be asked again and again.

Comment: @Johannes_B - I've decided to flag this posting as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mico I edit this question again. Would you consider to change the flag？ Thanks！

Comment: @Papiro   I edit this question again. Would you consider to change the flag？ Thanks！

Comment: @Stefan   I edit this question again. Would you consider to change the flag？ Thanks！

Comment: @Pinnow I edit this question again. Would you consider to change the flag？ Thanks！

Comment: @Kurt   I edit this question again. Would you consider to change the flag？ Thanks！

Comment: @Zarko  I edit this question again. Would you consider to change the flag？ Thanks！

Comment: @XJ.C - You should post a *new query* about citing a piece that's in Chinese. (I don't know anything about Chinese-language citation conventions.)

Comment: @Mico,  Should I post a new query or edit the question and explain how it is different from the exist answered question?

Comment: @XJ.C -- it's better to ask a new question, stating what you're trying to achieve as well as what's new about the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use the `natbib` citation management package and the `plainnat` bibliography style, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `plainnat_cn.bst`. (You're free to choose a different name, of course.)
- Open the file `plainnat_cn.bst` in an editor; the editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- Locate the function `format.lab.names`. (It starts on line 1101 in my copy of this file.) In case you're curious: This function serves to format the citation call-outs -- "labels" in bibliography jargon.
- In this function, locate the line

  ```
              { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
              { " 和 " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
  ```
- Save the file `plainnat_cn.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to refresh the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat_cn}` and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully update all links.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{citation.bib}
@article{eaton2002technology,
Author = {Eaton, Jonathan and Kortum, Samuel},
Journal = {Econometrica},
Number = {5},
Pages = {1741--1779},
Publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
Title = {Technology, geography, and trade},
Volume = {70},
Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat_cn} 

\begin{document}
我的中文文章参考了 \cite{eaton2002technology}
\bibliography{citation}
\end{document}
```