# How to change bibliography citation from 'and' to native language?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to have a citation but I my citation I have word 'and' which is english however paper I am currently working on has to be in a different language thus my question is how to change this 'and' to equivalent word in different languages?

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}   
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\author{Nice}
\title{Nice}
\begin{document}
    \section{Words on a printed page}
        Some random words
    \subsection{Words }



\newpage    
%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}

\end{document}
```

And sample bibliography entry:

```
@article{piketty2003income,
    title={Income inequality in the United States, 1913--1998},
    author={Piketty, Thomas and Saez, Emmanuel},
    journal={The Quarterly journal of economics},
    volume={118},
    number={1},
    pages={1--41},
    year={2003},
    publisher={MIT Press}
}
```

Simple removal of the word "and" from bib files does not work.

Comment: Done, everything you have ina question body... First one :)

Comment: I would argue that it is not a duplicate on macOS I cannot find file `plainnat.bst` either the name of this file is different or a location.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate. You didn't specify your 'native language'.The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19837/5001) to the earlier question assumes that the native language is German; if yours is French, Spanish, Italian, Catalan, or whatever, just use the applicable conjunction instead of `\&`.

Comment: You wrote, "I cannot find file plainnat.bst". In MacOS, do you know how to open a command window? If so, type `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` at a command prompt, and you'll find out where the file is located.